# Website login Issue in Selenium ChromeDriver

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, c#, chromedriver

I am login to a website using Selenium and ChromeDriver. But website login details are shown as incorrect every time. But I have manually logged into the site using Chrome browser easily.

How do I login to the website using Selenium and ChromeDriver without issue?

Code:

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.textnow.com/login");
driver.FindElement(By.Name("username")).SendKeys("pankajsingh42@gmail.com");
driver.FindElement(By.Name("password")).SendKeys("*********");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("btn-login")).Click();
```

Page example:

[image]

Comment: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Pankaj, could you share the HTML of the login page, alongside a screenshot of it and the code you have already written?

Comment: can you explain the scenario with more details for this issue(if you have code attach with this pls add it), So that we can figure that out?

Comment: IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.textnow.com/login");
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("username")).SendKeys("pankajsingh42@gmail.com");
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("password")).SendKeys("*********");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("btn-login")).Click();

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting? I have answered with a common error, but without the error it could be anything.

Comment: Add source code of the login form. It can help.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks like it could work, but maybe the page loads slow and you are trying to interact with an element that does not exist yet. Be sure you wait for the first element to be ready. I added a wait to your example.

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.textnow.com/login");

var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
var username = wait.Until(f => f.FindElement(By.Name("username")));

username.SendKeys("pankajsingh42@gmail.com");
driver.FindElement(By.Name("password")).SendKeys("*********");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("btn-login")).Click();
```

Comment: I think it's guessing not answering the question. Maybe there is no focus on the input form? Advanced CSS may cause some troubles.

Comment: @Bulat Maybe not answering the original question, but it could help others visiting this page with a similar issue. I also added a comment for more info on the error, than I will rewrite the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Like Niels said above, it could be the timing issue. You might wanna wait until the element exists in the page and then do the stuff. Like you can make a function called WaitUntilElementIsVisible, and call that function before you find any element in the page. Will be easier for you